# Fly into London (LTN) at late night

Tags: air-travel, planning, london, ltn

When I was planning my trip to London, I came across two option for me to fly to London.

1. Arriving on Friday's early morning (08:05)
2. Arriving on Thursday's late night (22:35)

When comparing these two option, the biggest difference is that I can save £10 for choosing option 2 even including the cost of accommodation in Thursday night. But flying in such a late hour can raise many concern, such as the availability of transport to the hostel (close to city center), the price of transport in those hours, safety etc.

Did anyone have the experience of arriving at LTN so late? Is there any advice about transport in London at night?

Comment: If LTN is Luton airport, is your "city center" hotel in Luton or in London? It makes a big difference. LTN is 30 miles from Marble Arch.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick The accommodation is in London, to be precise it is located within a few hundreds meter from Elephant and Castle

Comment: There are a bunch of hotels around Luton Airport, many of which have decent prices. Unless your hotel is right by the rail route from Luton, I'd suggest you look at booking one of those then head down to London in the morning

Comment: @Gagravarr When you referring to those hotel with decent price, which of them were you talking about? Since what I found in the internet at least cost around £30, but the hostel I picked in London only cost £10 a night

Comment: 30-60 quid for a Luton airport hotel sounds about right to me. For an airport hotel just outside london, those are decent prices

Comment: There are trains all night from Luton Airport Parkway to Blackfriars, and there are also overnight services from Blackfriars to Elephant & Castle, so you could actually do this journey realistically.  Much of London's public transport network shuts down about midnight, but this would be an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The morning option is much better, there's more trains and you can go direct to Elephant and Castle without needing to change trains.

Useful resources:

TfL journey planner: https://tfl.gov.uk/plan-a-journey/

Thameslink train timetable: http://www.thameslinkrailway.com/download/11029.2/b-all-thameslink-services/

By 8am you're right in the middle of the morning peak and everything should be running - but in the middle of the night it goes down to only 2 trains an hour from Luton Airport to London, and that train doesn't take you all the way to the Elephant. Go for the morning one.

Also, you can check in advance for scheduled engineering work here: http://www.thameslinkrailway.com/your-journey/engineering/

You have to get a bus from Luton airport to the railway station, it costs £2 and is cash only. Takes about 10 mins. http://www.london-luton.co.uk/to-and-from-lla/travelling-from-london-or-the-south

Comment: Hi again. Do you know if there's an mobile app version of the journey planner?

Comment: Hi @Edison - I use an app named CityMapper.